# RabbitMQ connected dockerized Windows app stops consuming messages after some idle minutes

Tags: windows, docker, hyper-v, rabbitmq

I have two Windows processes each in its own Docker container and they both publish and consume RabbitMQ messages. This is a proven app working on bare metal, but when dockerized it stops consuming messages after some idle period. Publishing still works as can be seen in RabbitMQ management, but the message is discarded after rabbit ttl of 15s.

Netstat -a inside both containers shows multiple "eastablished" tcp connections to port 5672 on Docker host.

RabbitMQ currently runs as a service on Docker host(no virtualization), but I tried running it on Docker desktop with the same effect.

The setup is Docker Desktop 4.19, running on Windows 10 Pro x64 v1909. Hyper-v switch is "nat" which I believe is the default Docker switch on Windows.

Comment: This was related to my consumer services connecting and listening to external IP of the host workstation(rabbitmq host). When I switched to using host.docker.internal as the rabbitmq host, the timeouts stopped happening.